# Скорость загрузки HTML

Tags: html, оптимизация-сайтов

[HTML-документ](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gcyxubqr3rokgpx/index1.html?dl=0)

Данный документ в некоторых браузерах загружается достаточно долго. Есть ли пути ускорения его загрузки путем изменения структуры (не содержимого) html-файла?

Comment: А трафик не пробовали сжимать, например, через mod_gzip (для апача)? Чтобы сервер отдавал не 3МБ, а значительно меньше

Answer (score 2):

Какая жесть...
Т.к. это вроде какой-то рассказ, то переделать его нельзя (ради пары байт в данном случае это из главного орудия Звезды Смерти по тараканам).
Решается это довольно просто - подели текст на куски, сразу грузи первый кусок и, с помощью AJAX, подгружай остальные по мере прокрутки.

Comment: Там не только рассказ, но и почти каждое второе слова выделено тегами `<b><i>`, если это выделение вырезать, то он на 1МБ с копейками уже меньше весить начинает

Comment: Это не типичный HTML-файл. Выделение слов курсивом и жирным обязательно :)

Comment: Читаешь между строк? :)
Надо строки читать, там же написано - содержимое не менять!
Я предложил изменить структуру, не содержимое.

Comment: Просто само задание на языке C# состоит в составлении этого документа с выделением определенных слов. А уже дополнительное требование: чтобы загружался html по-быстрее.

Comment: @kubito, Задание на C#, которое превращается в грязный HTML, который нужно грузить по HTTP быстрее? Жесть.
Тебе предложили две оптимизации: на сервере (сжимая код) и на клиенте (через JS подтягивать кусками).
Выбирай что по душе.

Comment: @kubito, а какое именно задание было? У вас много слов, которые выделены отдельно (например, `<i><b>молодой</b></i> <i><b>человек</b></i>`), их надо бы группировать (т.е. так `<i><b>молодой человек</b></i>`) - уже 0.5МБ сэкономили бы. А если еще и точки в такие группы добавлять - еще больше вышло бы. Такое решение пойдет или так делать нельзя? А JS можно в коде использовать? Можно было бы программно нужные слова в тексте выделять.

Comment: @BOPOH, Этот HTML изначально для сайта http://govnokod.ru/, видимо программа на шарпе делает свою работу из рук вон плохо. Или у кого-то руки кривые, раз такое написал.

Comment: Открывается HTML чисто в браузере с жесткого диска

Comment: @kubito, Угу, открывается с винта и передаётся в браузер... по сети :)

Answer (score 0):

Сегментируйте исходный код с [семантическими элементам ХТМЛ5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp). Обращайте внимание на порядок вложенности и [порядок очерёдности элементов титлы (h)](http://html5doctor.com/outlines/). Для проверки используйте [этот валидатор W3](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) с выбором фильтра outline и смотрите внизу результат в секциях Heading-level outline и Structural outline